# Why is time complexity of reversing a N digit integer is O(log N) and not O(N)?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, reverse

```
public class Main {
   static int reverse(int X) {
      int Y = 0;
      while (X > 0) {
         //Extract the last digit
         int digit = X % 10;
         //Appending last digit
         Y = Y * 10 + digit;
         // Shrinking X by discarding the last digit
         X = X / 10;
      }
      return Y;
   }
```

Why here time complexity is O(log n) and not O(n)??
Please explain?

Comment: Don't spam tags! Stop that!

Comment: Why do you think it's O(N)? How many times does this loop execute for 10,000? 100,000?

Comment: Clarify what is N? Number of digits or the literal value of X?

Comment: What is your source for the complexity being O(log n)? Does that source agree with your question's title that n is the number of digits?

Answer (score 3):

Its `O(N)` where `N` = number of digits in `X` or
it is `O(log X)` where log is logarithm to base 10.

Comment: Because [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/231745/135560).